# Flask routing problems

Tags: python, redirect, curl, flask

I'm practicing writing a rest api in flask, and I'd like to save a username as a session variable, and have it accessible in each route. I'd like to just interact with this program through the command line via curl.

```
from flask import Flask, Response, session, request, url_for, redirect
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'blabla'

@app.route('/')
def index():
  print 'Inside index route'
  if 'username' in session:
    username = session['username']
    print 'Logged in as {}'.format(username)
    return Response(response='Logged In\n', status=200, mimetype='text')
  else:
    print 'Not logged in'
    return Response(response='Not Logged In\n', status=200, mimetype='text')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  print 'Inside login route'
  if request.method == 'POST':
    session['username'] = json.loads(request.data)['username']
    print session['username']
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
  session.pop('username', None)
  return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

When I curl the site with:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1:5000/login -d '{"username": "mdito"}'
```

I get the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="/">/</a>.  If not click the link.
```

On the server side I am seeing:

```
Inside login route
mdito
```

If I'm redirecting to the index url, why does 'Inside index route' not appear on the server side? And why does 'Logged In' not get returned to the user?

Comment: `curl` won't follow redirect by default. You should use `curl -L`

Answer (score 9):

Because flask does 302 redirect from `/url` to `/url/`. To avoid redirects add `/` at the end:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

[Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) (see `Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior` part). That's it.